# I want to find a similar API to org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion to verify if one image exists in another

Tags: python, webdriver, sikuli, appium

I'm writing Python code for IOS automation using Appium, but get stuck on this issue:
    the check point is check some cells in tableView, when changing the device location setting (the cells will be different, both number and text), if the text and image appears in cell correctly, and the image matches the text, like football icon matches "football", I try to find webdriver api to capture the snapshot for the cell only, but all the methods I found are for the driver, it just can capture the whole screen.

```
so we found a way to check this: first we capture the correct screenshot for the cells manually, then running the automation script, use the correct cell_screenshot to check if it appears in the screen
```

### now my workmates has the java code for this:

```
import org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion;
import org.sikuli.api.ImageTarget;
import org.sikuli.api.ScreenRegion;
import org.sikuli.api.Target;

public class SnapShot {
    static DesktopScreenRegion sr = new DesktopScreenRegion();
    static Target image;
    static ScreenRegion result;
    static String fileURL;

    private static String getImageURL(String fileURL){
        return "screenshots/" + fileURL; 
    }`enter code here`
    public static boolean imageExists(String fileURL, Double similar, int timeout){
    timeout = timeout * 1000;
    image = new ImageTarget(new File(getImageURL(fileURL)));
    image.setMinScore(similar);
    result = sr.wait(image, timeout);
    if (result == null){
            System.out.println("Can not find image");
            return false;
    }
    return true;
    }
}
```

---

this code can use imageExists to judge if the image can be found in another
I search for sikuli api for python, but cannot find anything, looks like there's java api only
now I'm stuck at this, could anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli supports Jython as well. In fact that is default the scripting language for Sikuli. So you can write similar logic in Jython and then call that script from Python(if at all you can). I have seen users using Java to call sikuli script. Refer [here](http://doc.sikuli.org/) for Sikuli details.